# Picking up and Dropping Items

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2015

I'm building a Text based RPG where the user has an inventory in which they can pick up and place items in. I've set up my inventory to have 6 slots:

```
string inventory[] = { "Empty Slot", "Empty Slot", "Empty Slot", 
                       "Empty Slot", "Empty Slot", "Empty Slot" };
```

If I want to print my inventory, I use a for loop like this:

```
void getInventory() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        cout << inventory[i];
}// if there is another way to do this, please suggest!
```

But I'm having some trouble adding items to my inventory. If a user enters a room with a key inside, and types in `"pickup"`, the key should go into an inventory slot like this:

```
if (input == "PICKUP" || input == "pickup") {

        inventory[0] = "Shiny Key";
}
```

With this code, how do I check that this particular slot is **now filled**? For example, if all slots are filled with keys and the user attempts to pick something up, how can I check that the inventory is full?

Also, if a user types in `"drop"`, how can I make it so the user can specifically pick which slot they want to drop?

Comment: To begin with you have an off-by-one error, where you go out of bounds of your inventory array.

Comment: As for the first part of your problem, you could check for the string `"Empty Slot"` to find the first empty slot. For the second part, add *keywords* to your items. So a `"Shiny Key"` could have the keywords `shiny` and `key`. Then the user could use `drop key` to drop the first key, or `drop shiny key` to drop the shiny key.

Comment: If I were you I would write my own container that wraps a `std::vector`.  It will keep track of what the max size is and if you hit it adding things into the vector, it will stop you from adding more elements.  Does require some boiler plate to forward function but IMHO it gives you a nice reusable inventory you can use in other places.

Comment: There's a completely different approach you could use instead: Every object in the world has a `location` (possibly represented as an `int`), and the player's inventory is just one of them. To move an item to inventory (or to anywhere in fact), check it's OK to move it, then change the item's `location` to the inventory's ID. If you keep all your items in a `vector` you can very quickly loop through and find which items have an inventory `location`.

Comment: @NathanOliver could you give an example of how you'd implement that with a vector?

Comment: @LucyLoo Something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d02dfe2660a73aaf).  You could even change from using a `vector` to a `map` so you can keep track of items and quantities.